# How can I divide a line segment into equidistant parts in Matlab?

Tags: geometry, matlab

I have two parallel *line segments* of different lengths. I have the endpoints of each line segment.

I want to have equidistant points on both line segments and then join the corresponding points on both line segments with a set of lines.

Comment: So what prevents you from doing it? We can primarily answer mathematical questions, so where are you stuck. We most likely cannot generate code for you.

Comment: @M. Winter I am stuck at the question on how to mathematically divide the line in say 100 equidistant point with (x,y) coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your line goes from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_2,y_2)$, then $n$ equidistant points on the line are given by

$$\frac i{n-1}(x_1,y_1) + \left(1-\frac i{n-1}\right)(x_2,y_2), \qquad \text{for $i=0,...,n-1$}.$$

Comment: thank you for your help...cheers...!!!